# What GitLab CI configuration will reliably cache Haskell package dependencies built by cabal?

Tags: haskell, caching, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cabal

I have a Haskell project that builds using cabal.  I have GitLab-based CI set up for it.

The GitLab CI configuration includes this job definition:

```
cabal-build-and-test:
  cache:
    key: "v0-cabal"
    when: "always"
    paths:
      - ".cabal"

  script:
    - |
      cat >cabal.project.local <<EOF
      store-dir: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cabal
      remote-repo-cache: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cabal/packages
      EOF
      nix run .#cabal-test
```

The `cabal-test` nix app is defined to run:

```
cabal update hackage.haskell.org
cabal build
cabal run tests
```

Often builds succeed.  However, sometimes (it's not clear what conditions lead to this case), they fail with errors like:

```
37 | import Hedgehog.Internal.Report
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
src/Test/Tasty/Hedgehog.hs:38:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Hedgehog.Internal.Seed’
    There are files missing in the ‘hedgehog-1.2’ package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
38 | import Hedgehog.Internal.Seed as Seed
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: cabal: Failed to build tasty-hedgehog-1.4.0.1
```

This seems to point at the GitLab-managed cache of some of cabal's files being incomplete or otherwise corrupt.

How do I change this configuration so the cache works reliably - making previously-built package artifacts available to new builds and not provoking these build failures?

Comment: So I suppose my answer didn't work?

Comment: I haven't gotten a chance to try it yet :/  I hope to be able to revisit this but it will probably be another week minimum before I have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `~/.cabal/config` or `cabal.project` settings in the context of this pipeline: if nothing is configured, that means by default you have *both* `.cabal` *and* `dist-newstyle` to consider for caching: `cabal` stores built packages in the `dist-newstyle` directory (see [`haskell/cabal` issue 5731](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5731)).

Modify the `paths` section under the cache configuration in your GitLab CI job definition.

And it might be better to modify your cache key and make it more specific by including variables that represent the environment.
This ensures that the cache is only used in compatible environments.

For example:

```yaml
cabal-build-and-test:
  cache:
    key: "v0-cabal-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
    when: "always"
    paths:
      - ".cabal"
      - "dist-newstyle"

  script:
    # ... rest of the script
```

The  `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` is a [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) in GitLab CI that contains the branch or tag name for which the pipeline is running. Using this variable as part of the cache key ensures that each branch/tag has its separate cache, which can be useful to avoid conflicts between dependencies or build artifacts of different branches.

By specifying the cache key as `"v0-cabal-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"`, this configuration ensures that, for example, the `main` branch and a feature branch like `feature-xyz` do not share the same cache. This can prevent potential conflicts between different versions of dependencies used in different branches.

You could also replace your `cabal build` with `ghc-pkg check --verbose || cabal update && cabal build --only-dependencies`, to get more details.

---

> I was able to test a change that added "dist-newstyle" to the cache paths but after just a couple CI runs the error about "missing files" re-appeared.

It is possible for caches to get corrupted in some CI environments. As a first step, you could try invalidating the cache. Change the cache key (e.g., from `"v0-cabal"` to `"v1-cabal"`) to force a cache miss in the next run, thereby rebuilding everything.

But consider also a fallback strategy: Whenever a build fails due to a package issue, clear the `dist-newstyle` and `.cabal` directories and try building again. While that is not efficient, it can be a temporary measure while diagnosing the problem.

```yaml
script:
  - |
    # the usual build steps
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "Build failed. Clearing dist-newstyle and .cabal and retrying..."
      rm -rf dist-newstyle .cabal
      # rebuild commands
    fi
```

Comment: I was able to test a change that added "dist-newstyle" to the cache paths but after just a couple CI runs the error about "missing files" re-appeared.

Comment: Thanks.  Interesting idea to clear the cache and retry automatically on error, I may try that.  As far as an initial cache reset goes, I did  exactly that before trying with the new path list so the failure I was reported was against a freshly created cache.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone OK. Can you confirm there is no multiple jobs are writing to or reading from the same cache concurrently?

Also, can you double-check there are no environment differences between agents during the CI run? That would include: `cabal --version`, `ghc --version`, `ghc-pkg list`, `ls -al` on critical paths like `.cabal` and `dist-newstyle`.